# Compiling to a different python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, compilation

I have an application written in `python 2.7` . In my app I want to give users the ability to compile a python source file (i.e `py` to `pyc`).

The builtin `compile` function does this but the output file is only compatible with `python 2.7`.

What I want is to compile the file to a range of different python versions (specifically python `2.5` , `2.6` & `2.7` )

I know that one way to approach this problem is re-write my application in each of those versions and just use the inbuilt `compile` function, but I do not want to do this.

I am open to all suggestions including writing a C extension, embedding python etc...

**EDIT**

The application which I am writing is a tool which allows to inject/modify arbitrary code inside a pyinstaller exe.

Now you may be knowing that pyinstaller actually puts compiled python source files within the exe. 
My app just extracts these embedded pyc files, decompiles them, allows the user to modify them, and then rebuild the exe.

Since the exe can be from a different python version, so I need the functionality to compile the decompiled output to that version.

Here is a screenshot of that app.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you use a Python install tool like `pip` this is done for you on install. And Python automatically does this when running the code anyway, provided there is write access at import time.

Comment: And the built-in `compile()` function does **not** produce `.pyc` files. You can use the [`compileall` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html) to have Python produce those files for a whole directory or individual files instead. Just use `python-2.5 -m compileall /path/to/project` to do so with the Python 2.5 interpreter, for example.

Comment: `pyinstaller` installs code **with a specific Python version**. There is **no need** to precompile there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah i know all details of the `compile` function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really? (I'm not a pythonist so far) This sounds great, but how are version incompatibilities in source code handled "automatically"? I assume producing compatible code is the point here. Isn't it?

Comment: @hek2mgl: you generally install libraries in a *per version* structure. `/usr/lib/python-2.7/site-packages`, etc. Python will ignore bytecode caches if they are for the wrong version anyway and it cannot rewrite them.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Python 3.2 and newer uses a [per version cache directory](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.2.html#pep-3147-pyc-repository-directories) instead of `.pyc` files in the same directory.

Comment: Can you install the different python versions? Then you can execute scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem in a different approach.

Now, my main app is written in python `2.7`. I wrote 2 `dll` each of which had a  python interpreter embedded. Within one I embedded python `2.6` and within other python `2.5`.
Each of these two dlls uses the Python C API to compile a script given as an argument to the respective python version.

Now, from my main app (written in python `2.7`) , I used `ctypes` to call the exported functions from these two dlls. The script to compile was passed as an argument.

Using this approach I was able to compile a given script to any of the 3 python versions.